# Calculate time of multiple rows when parameters are met

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I want to calculate the elapsed time from multiple rows where specific parameters are met. Here is my query

```
SELECT 
 EventDate AS 'Date'
,ID
,DeptCode 'DC'
,OpCode 'OC'
,ElapsedTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime),0)) 
,Units = SUM(Units)
,UPH = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
FROM dbo.TimeLog WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE EventDate = '06/15/17' AND DeptCode = 'ST' AND OpCode = 'BT' 
GROUP BY 
   EventDate, ID, DeptCode, OpCode, StartTime, FinishTime
ORDER BY  UPH DESC
```

Here is the results...

```
Date    ID      DC  OC  ElapsedTime Units   UPH
6/15/17 2375278 ST  BT  00:48:00    3262    4077
6/15/17 2375278 ST  BT  03:15:00    4730    1455
6/15/17 2375278 ST  BT  00:12:00    NULL    0
6/15/17 2375278 ST  BT  00:30:00    NULL    0
6/15/17 2375278 ST  BT  00:30:00    NULL    0
6/15/17 2375278 ST  BT  00:45:00    NULL    0
6/15/17 2375278 ST  BT  03:20:00    NULL    0
6/15/17 2375278 ST  BT  00:40:00    NULL    0
```

What I would like to see is this as my results

```
Date    ID      DC  OC  ElapsedTime Units   UPH
6/15/17 2375278 ST  BT  10:00:00    7992    799
```

Can someone help script this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Date], ID, DC, OC, sum(ElapsedTime), sum(Units), sum(UPH)
  from (SELECT EventDate AS 'Date'
               ,ID
               ,DeptCode 'DC'
               ,OpCode 'OC'
               [...]
       ) subquery
 group by [Date], ID, DC, OC;
```

Comment: Just tried that query, does not work as ElapsedTime and UPH are not columns in the table

Comment: Yes, but they are columns of your SELECT. Use your existing SELECT and put the SELECT I posted around it.

Comment: Oh yes, I receive a error message, Column 'dbo.TimeLog.EventDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Use your complete SELECT (which was working until now, right?) as the inner query for my outer query.

Comment: The "GROUP BY" part is missing, that's why I said "use your COMPLETE SELECT ...".